# React Native Screen wont re-render after fetching data and setting state using HTTP request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, http, axios

I am using the react-native google API to request calendar data via HTTP request using axios.

After the user clicks a login button the function `calendarData` is initiated and successfully pulls the data and I use `setCalendarEvents` to set the state of my page to this response data.

I expected this to re-render the screen and display the data but it is not...How can I initiate a page refresh after this data is received from the HTTP request without a manual re-render?

STATE

```
const [calendarEvents, setCalendarEvents] = useState([]);
```

calendarData function RUNS AFTER LOG IN BUTTON IS PRESSED BY USER

```
const calendarData = async function signInWithGoogleAsync() {
    try {
      const result = await Google.logInAsync({
        androidClientId: `['CLIENT ID]`,
        iosClientId: `['CLIENT ID']`,
        scopes: [
          "profile",
          "email",
          "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar",
          "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events",
        ],
      });

      if (result.type === "success") {

        axios({
//HTTP GET REQUEST FOR DATA
          method: "get",
          baseURL: "https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/['USER CALENDAR]/events?key=['API KEY']",

          headers: {
            Authorization: "Bearer " + result.accessToken,
            Accept: "application/json",
          },
        })
          .then((response) => {
            const responseDataArray = [];
//RESPONSE DATA
            response.data["items"].map((event) => {
              if (typeof event["start"].dateTime !== undefined) {
                responseDataArray.push(event);
              }
//SET STATE TO RETREIVED AND FILTERED DATA STORED IN responseDataArray
              setCalendarEvents(responseDataArray);
            });
          })
//CATCH ERRORS
          .catch((error) => console.log(error));
      } else {
        return { cancelled: true };
      }
    } catch (e) {
      return { error: true };
    }
  };
```

WHERE DATA SHOULD BE RENDERED ON THE SCREEN AFTER SUCCESSFUL GET

```
return (

<View>
   {calendarEvents.map((event) => {
     <View>{event}</View>
          }
     }
</View>

)
```

EXAMPLE OF RESPONSE DATA ITEM

I am looking to filter out `"start":{"dateTime":"2021-04-16T17:30:00-04:00"}` if it exists

```
{"kind":"calendar#event","etag":"\"3237003518996000\"","id":"7t1q67ai1p7t586peevd7s9mhg","status":"confirmed","htmlLink":"https://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=N3QxcTY3YWkxcDd0NTg2cGVldmQ3czltaGcgbWF0dEBoZWFydGhkaXNwbGF5LmNvbQ","created":"2021-04-14T16:45:34.000Z","updated":"2021-04-15T15:49:19.498Z","summary":"customer journey beta buddies","creator":{"email":"meilin@hearthdisplay.com"},"organizer":{"email":"meilin@hearthdisplay.com"},"start":{"dateTime":"2021-04-16T17:30:00-04:00"},"end":{"dateTime":"2021-04-16T18:30:00-04:00"},"iCalUID":"7t1q67ai1p7t586peevd7s9mhg@google.com","sequence":0,"attendees":[{"email":"meilin@hearthdisplay.com","organizer":true,"responseStatus":"accepted"},{"email":"matt@hearthdisplay.com","self":true,"optional":true,"responseStatus":"accepted"},{"email":"susie@hearthdisplay.com","responseStatus":"accepted"},{"email":"nathalie@hearthdisplay.com","responseStatus":"accepted"}],"hangoutLink":"https://meet.google.com/xyb-qhpb-uej","conferenceData":{"entryPoints":[{"entryPointType":"video","uri":"https://meet.google.com/xyb-qhpb-uej","label":"meet.google.com/xyb-qhpb-uej"},{"entryPointType":"more","uri":"https://tel.meet/xyb-qhpb-uej?pin=3822838393771","pin":"3822838393771"},{"regionCode":"US","entryPointType":"phone","uri":"tel:+1-818-514-5197","label":"+1 818-514-5197","pin":"222000933"}],"conferenceSolution":{"key":{"type":"hangoutsMeet"},"name":"Google Meet","iconUri":"https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/i/productlogos/meet_2020q4/v6/web-512dp/logo_meet_2020q4_color_2x_web_512dp.png"},"conferenceId":"xyb-qhpb-uej","signature":"AGirE/Jmi4pFHkq0kcqgRyOuAR2r"},"reminders":{"useDefault":true},"eventType":"default"}
```

Comment: Have you proved to yourself yet that responseDataArray is definitely a list containing stuff?

Comment: Oh and don't call setCalendarEvents in the map. Since it's an asynchronous function that just doesn't make sense. Instead compute what you want the new state to be, then set it once.

Comment: I did confirm that the the response data array contains all of the response data i requested thats why I was getting confused because its there but doesnt seem to be setting new state correctly which i thought would cause a re-render...let me give it a shot

Comment: if I move setCalendarEvents outside of the map it seems to not be setting the state anymore though

Comment: Have you logged responseDataArray right before you set it as state? What is it?

Comment: yes I actually found where I was running into an issue and whats not causing the render: when i filter the data (which is calendar data) using event["start"].dateTime....if "dateTime" in my object is "undefined" i get an error so then it doesnt render.....if i remove this filter it renders but then I cant access the date so im still stuck in a way

Comment: By filter do you mean your `if (typeof time !== undefined)` line? That doesn't do anything because the typeof operator always returns a string. If you show an example of what reponse.data.items is, I can easily show the code that will make the list you want.

Comment: Oh and  your `calendarEvents.map` doesn't actually return anything. This is a really common error in JS because without the braces there's an implicit return. It's easy to catch this by first logging `calendarEvents` and making sure it's a list with stuff in it, then checking the DOM to see if there's a <View> tag for each one. Then you can easily debug from there.

Comment: And just for kicks: to get rid of the mutation you can write `setCalendarEvents((response.data?.items || []).filter(e => e?.start?.dateTime ?? false));` instead.

Comment: yes I can share more or maybe make it another question but im filtering if the string time is literally equalled to the string "undefined" not using type...I should try using type instead this makes sense....thanks ! let me try these suggesstions i really appreaciate it .

Comment: And yes it would be good to see basically i need to filter out events for todays current date and filter out events that dont have a start time attached to them hence the "undefined"

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try with this, add conditional rendering :

```
return ({
  calendarEvents.length>0 &&
    calendarEvents?.map(...your code) 
})
```

Comment: i tried this and I am still gettting the same results as before. I would think that this solution would work tho so I am wondering where the mistake I made is....